# Как понять на какое слово я навел в тексте tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора на какое-либо слово, оно переключалось на курсив. При убирании курсора - обратно в обычный текст. Также нужно, чтобы значение этого слова сохранялось в какую-то переменную.
Сейчас есть идея вешать ка каждое слово в Text свой тег и что-то с этим потом делать.

Comment: В Label - никак. В Entry или в Text - можно. В Text это сделать проще чем в Entry.

Comment: @GrAnd да, мне текст и нужен. Я так понял там это можно как-то с тегами сделать, но как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, вот примерно так это делается:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

root = tk.Tk()

def on_mouse_move(event):
    text.tag_remove("highlight", "1.0", tk.END)
    word = text.get(f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordstart", f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordend")
    if word.isalpha():
        text.tag_add("highlight", f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordstart", f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordend")

text = tk.Text(root)
italic_font = tkFont.nametofont(text.cget("font")).copy()
italic_font.config(slant=tkFont.ITALIC)
text.tag_config("highlight", font=italic_font, foreground="yellow", background="#a00")
text.bind("<Motion>", on_mouse_move)
text.grid()

text.insert(tk.END, """Давеча Витька сказал, что идет в одну компанию, а в лаборатории оставляет работать дубля. 
Дубль – это очень интересная штука. Как правило, это довольно точная копия своего творца. 
Не хватает, скажем, человеку рук – он создает себе дубля, безмозглого, безответного, только и умеющего, что паять контакты, или таскать тяжести, или писать под диктовку, но зато уж умеющего это делать хорошо. 
Или нужна человеку модель-антропоид для какого-нибудь эксперимента – он создает себе дубля, безмозглого, безответного, только и умеющего, что ходить по потолку или принимать телепатемы, но зато уж умеющего хорошо. 
Или самый простой случай. Собирается, скажем, человек получить зарплату, а времени терять ему не хочется, и он посылает вместо себя своего дубля, только и умеющего, что никого без очереди не пропускать, расписываться в ведомости и сосчитать деньги, не отходя от кассы. 
Конечно, творить дублей умеют не все. Я, например, еще не умел. То, что у меня пока получалось, ничего не умело – даже ходить. 
И вот стоишь, бывало, в очереди, вроде бы тут и Витька, и Роман, и Володя Почкин, а поговорить не с кем. 
Стоят как каменные, не мигают, не дышат, с ноги на ногу не переминаются, и сигарету спросить не у кого.""")

root.mainloop()
```

Только из-за курсива текст может подёргиваться, т.к. курсивный шрифт может иметь высоту несколько отличную от нормального написания.
Лучше, как мне кажется, использовать для выделения подчёркнутый шрифт (`italic_font.config(underline=True)`)или выделять цветом.